# Creating a javascript object with prototyping (no privacy)

Tags: javascript

Can I put similar methods in an associative aray like this?

```
var function_hold = {   
  function1: function(){}
  function2: function (){}
 };
```

If not,

How do I group similar methods?

Comment: Yes, though strictly speaking it's a stretch to call JavaScript objects "associative arrays".  (The property namespace of an object can be "polluted" somewhat through prototypal inheritance effects.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly as you would with any other object-oriented programming language, you group functionality in objects. This works in JavaScript as well.

Your code actually creates an object. Alternatively you can use JavaScript's prototype mechanism.

```
var Person = function(firstname, surname){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.surname = surname;
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function(){
    return this.firstname + " " + this.surname;
}
```

You then call it like

```
var tom = new Person("Tom", "Jackwood");
tom.getFullName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes thats possible and works fine.

Best Practice syntax would be the [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)

```
var outerNamespace = {};

(function(ns) {
   // ns is the local name of the object
   ns.function1 = function() {}
   ns.function2 = function() {}

  //self executing anonymous function
} (outerNamespace));
```

Comment: Yes it is, whats the question?

Comment: They can be used like classes in other OO-Languages. They simply give you a namespace to operate in.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that should would just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work fine. You can call the functions with `function_hold.function1()`.

Note that normally you'll want to associate data with the functions as well:

```
var function_hold = {
    x: 0,
    function1: function(){
        this.x++;
    }
    function2: function(){
        alert(this.x);
    }
};
```